# Find Segments that form a Closed Loop in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

I have to find complex intersections where 8 roads meet each other. When they cross, they form a rectangle in the middle that is a closed loop (see Figure). My idea to find the intersections is to find these loops. My initial thought was to use ST_Intersections, but maybe it's takin forever. I don't care what I use to solve the problem, as long as it does.

Each road has a "startpoint" and a "endpoint" and I noticed that the values are the same among them, so if I put them into an array and order it, it's the same array. That's the only thing I can see that they have in common.

Example:

> segmentkey
> 13957 14058 14064 532476

> startpoint
> 14835 14956 14836 14962

> endpoint
> 14836 14835 14962 14956

As one can see, the start points and end points are the same.

[image]